# CASE condition in SELECT statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have CASE condition  in SELECT. Below is the query condition

The query is from a view

```
SELECT expt_id,stain_type,control_stain, test_stain
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Blue' THEN control_stain = 'NA'
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Hemat' THEN test_stain = 'NA'
FROM experiment_results__view
```

Here the value 'NA' has to be populated for the condition of stain_type. Would appreciate your help with suggestions on how to write this query

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add example data ans expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you want to use something in the line:

```
SELECT 
   expt_id,
   stain_type,
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Blue' THEN 'NA' ELSE NULL END control_stain, 
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Hemat' THEN 'NA' ELSE NULL END test_stain
FROM experiment_results__view
```

to get your value of 'NA' into columns named control_stain and test_stain.
But if you want to override the existing value in those columns with the value 'NA' in just those cases, then use:

```
SELECT 
   expt_id,
   stain_type,
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Blue' THEN 'NA' ELSE control_stain END control_stain, 
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Hemat' THEN 'NA' ELSE test_stain END test_stain
FROM experiment_results__view
```

If you're intending an update of your table then you should rewrite this to:

```
UPDATE 
   experiment_results__view 
SET 
   control_stain = CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Blue' THEN 'NA' ELSE control_stain END, 
   test_stain = CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Hemat' THEN 'NA' ELSE test_stain END
-- if you don't want to update the complete table add an WHERE clause
WHERE
   <some condition>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to END each case statement

```
SELECT expt_id,stain_type,
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Blue' THEN 'NA' ELSE control_stain END AS 'Control Stain'
   CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Hemat' THEN 'NA' ELSE test_stain END AS 'Test Stain'
FROM experiment_results__view
```

if you are intending to update the table  you can do an update query

```
UPDATE 
    experiment_results__view
SET 
    control_stain = CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Blue'  THEN 'NA' ELSE control_stain END,
    test_stain    = CASE WHEN stain_type = 'Hemat' THEN 'NA' ELSE test_stain END
```

Comment: John, Thanks for quick response. How do I explicitly assing to columns - as control_stain = 'NA' for case 1 and test_stain = 'NA' for case 2?

Comment: @user3130236 if you mean assign to column as in name the column see my update

Comment: @user3130236 or do you mean how to update the table?

Comment: To clarify, this is a view (experiment_results_view) and I can cant update the table. What I would need is that the values in those columns (control_stain and test_stain) have to be overidden for the specific stain types. To give a context, there are other stain types for which the values in those columns should be as is.

Comment: @user3130236 so what are you trying to do? get those values stored? or just change them when you select the data out?

Comment: Hi John - I would need to change them when retrieving. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3130236 did you try running the first query I wrote?